# How do I find out the version of CryptoJS that is installed with Postman?

Tags: postman, hmac, cryptojs

I need to know which version of CryptoJS is installed with Postman so I can accurately compare .NET and CryptoJS HMAC256 results.

Comment: What does Postman use CryptoJS for? Also, you could just locate the crx file of postman on you drive and look into it.

Comment: Thanks for replying but in the end I didnt need to know. I just needed to call the function CryptoJS.HmacSHA256 with my specific requirements.